# Graph theory/pigeonhole question.

Tags: graph-theory

In a waiting room, there are 100 people, each of whom knows 67 others among the 100. Prove that there exist 4 people in the waiting room who all know each other (that is, each know the other 3). You assume that knowing is mutual (if A knows B, then B knows A).

I understand that if there are 4 people in the waiting room who all know each other, that makes K_4, or a connected graph. However, the "67 others among the 100" part stumps me. Can someone give a hint/hints? Please do not solve the problem for me or give me the answer. I only need a hint/hints to get me started.

Thanks for all of your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the hint you want:

You're trying to find 4 people who know each other? Well, take one person at random, and ask yourself "where can I find the second person?", and you when you find the 2°, ask "where can I find the third?", and the same for the fourth.

**Bonus** You can try to prove a stronger question: prove that for every three people that know each other there exists a person that knows all of them

Comment: By "Where can I find the third", do you mean finding the third in relation to the first AND second person picked, or just the first person? If it is the first AND second person picked, and each of those two know 67 people, would we have to find the # of intersection to find the # of possibilities for the third person? Let me know if what I said doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the third person must know both the first and the second. The fourth must know the other three.

So, you can pick the third one in the set of people who know both the first and the second. How many there are, at least?

Comment: Person A knows 67 people. Person B knows 67 people--67+67 = 134. 134-98 (98, because we're not counting A or B) = 36. 36 possibilities for Person C? However--would finding the possibilities really matter/aid me in provin this problem?

Comment: yes, it helps you a lot, but 36 is not the right answer:
B knows A and other 66 people, A knows B and other 66 people, so the intersection is 66+66-98=34

Comment: Ah I see. So for Person D, than we would do: 66+66+66-97 = possibilities for D. Then I'll combine the results all together to solve the problem?

Comment: for person D is slightly more complicated than that. But I assure you that when you'll find the right answer, you'll understand immediately that is correct ;)

Comment: Alright! Thanks a bunch, Exodd! I thumbs-upped your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is by letting this be a graph since you tagged this problem graph theory.

Consider the waiting room as a a graph, where each vertex corresponds to a member, and a pair of vertices is connected by an edge if the corresponding members know each other. So the degree of every vertex is between $67$ and $99$ inclusive, so there are $33$ different possible degrees. We need to show that $4$ vertices have the same degree.